How to make text appear in front of fill when using tikzmarknode?
I've produced the following output:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, tikzmark, positioning, fit}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={red, -{stealth[length=10mm, blue]}, line width=0.5mm, line cap=round}}

\tikzset{lrarrow/.style={red, {stealth[length=10mm, blue]}-{stealth[length=10mm, blue]}, line width=0.5mm}}

\tikzset{block1/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, fill=red!5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \tikzmarknode{a1}{a}^2 + b^2 = \tikzmarknode{c1}{c}^2 \hspace{2cm} \tikzmarknode{a2}{a} = \ \tikzmarknode{cb}{\sqrt{c^2-b^2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node[block1, fit=(cb)] (bla) {};
    \draw[arrow, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=1pt] (a1.north) to[out=70, in=120] (a2.north);
    \draw[lrarrow, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=8pt] (c1) to (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

My problem is that the text inside the node is covered up when using the fill=color command. Removing that from block1, I get my output displayed:

Can anyone figure out a solution such that my output is still displayed when using fill?

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, tikzmark}
\tikzset{
arrow/.style={red, -{stealth[length=10mm, blue]}, line width=0.5mm, line cap=round},
lrarrow/.style={red, {stealth[length=10mm, blue]}-{stealth[length=10mm, blue]}, line width=0.5mm},
block1/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, fill=red!5, inner sep=.3333em},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \tikzmarknode{a1}{a}^2 + b^2 = \tikzmarknode{c1}{c}^2 \hspace{2cm} \tikzmarknode{a2}{a} = \ \tikzmarknode[block1]{cb}{\sqrt{c^2-b^2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \draw[arrow, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=2pt] (a1.north) to[out=70, in=120] (a2.north);
  \draw[lrarrow, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=8pt] (c1) to (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Whaaaaat, you can actually insert the specification itself inside of the \tikzmarknode!? I thought the purpose of it was only to reference external elements in other environments in order to use them inside of tikzpicture. Seems like the capabilities of tikz really extends beyond what I thought was possible - Ty for ur simple yet effective solution!

@Atex this is the correct solution. There are several variants of tikzmark in the library, the basic \tikzmark just remembers a point on the page, but \tikzmarknode also creates a node around its contents which can be styled as a regular node. (I recommend reading the documentation, and if you think something is missing or unclear then let me know - documentation isn't my strong point)

@Atex This is indeed the correct solution. It should appear first.

@AndrewStacey I see, then it makes sense to insert as many of the commands directly as possible (which means that one should only ever use tikzpicture if you actually need to draw something and not just nodes, right?)
Also, I just realized that this solution has the added benefit of making the fit library redundant since it's no longer needed to place the content inside of the node. I actually guess that had to do with the improper formatting, because I've never had problems with the text layering on top of a node with fill before the usage of it!

@jlab thanks for the heads up. I didn't realize you could add a checkmark to the most useful/correct answer in order to make it appear on top. It's done now and should appear first

A workaround is to play with the blend mode. Try something like
\tikzset{block1/.style={
    rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw=red, fill=red!5,
    blend mode=overlay
  }
}

Full example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, tikzmark, positioning, fit}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={
    red, -{stealth[length=10mm, blue]},
    line width=0.5mm, line cap=round
  }
}

\tikzset{lrarrow/.style={
    red, {stealth[length=10mm, blue]}-{stealth[length=10mm, blue]},
    line  width=0.5mm
  }
}

\tikzset{block1/.style={
    rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw=red, fill=red!5,
    blend mode=overlay
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \tikzmarknode{a1}{a}^2 + b^2
  = \tikzmarknode{c1}{c}^2 \hspace{2cm} \tikzmarknode{a2}{a}
  = \ \tikzmarknode{cb}{\sqrt{c^2-b^2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node[block1, fit=(cb)] (bla) {};
    \draw[arrow, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=1pt] (a1.north) to[out=70, in=120] (a2.north);
    \draw[lrarrow, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=8pt] (c1) to (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Ooooooh, this is an interesting solution which also opens up doors for experimenting with some new things, thanks!:)

Like this ? to redraw the text on the node ?

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, tikzmark, positioning, fit, backgrounds}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={red, -{stealth[length=10mm, blue]}, line width=0.5mm, line cap=round}}
\tikzset{lrarrow/.style={red, {stealth[length=10mm, blue]}-{stealth[length=10mm, blue]}, line width=0.5mm}}
\tikzset{block1/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, fill=red!5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \tikzmarknode{textnode}{a}^2 + b^2 = \tikzmarknode{c1}{c}^2 \hspace{2cm} \tikzmarknode{a2}{a} = \ \tikzmarknode{cb}{\sqrt{c^2-b^2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    % the background first
    \node[block1, fit=(cb), inner sep=4pt] (background) {};
    % Put the text node on top
    \node[anchor=base] at (cb.base) {\(\sqrt{c^2-b^2}\)};
    \draw[arrow, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=1pt] (textnode.north) to[out=70, in=120] (a2.north);
    \draw[lrarrow, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=8pt] (c1) to (a2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


But this way you call it manually twice and also have to put the text in the node. I wanted to use the tikzmark library with the purpose of not having to rewrite the expression(s) inside the tikzpicture environment again and just specify the drawing part to the equation I referenced.
I just want to clarify that idk if this is even possible, but I'm almost certain there's a workaround. I'd guess it'd have to do with somehow letting the tikzpicture environment know that the marked nodes must appear in front of the drawing(s).
Tyvm for still providing this solution!:)

@Atex Brute force solution indeed :) I'm sure TeXpert will find an elegant by-pass.

I hope so - Otherwise we'll have to resort to the brute force solution;)
