Is decorations.text not properly compatible with the tikzmark library?
I've tried getting this strange error message across 2 different documents so far (that I've tested), and it only happens when I combine the usage of tikzmark with decorations.text, both of which are libraries from tikz. Take a look at this:

The even stranger thing is, however, that this exact code usually works without any error, and to "quick fix" it, I just have to delete the amounts of code relating to postaction, recompile, then insert them again, recompile, and I get my normal output back:

This is a longer document as it's a part of an assignment, but here's the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows.meta, bending, positioning, decorations.text}
\tikzset{arrow/.style={-{Stealth[blue, length=3mm]}, line width=0.5mm, red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Reduceret rækkeechelonform} \\
        &\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right] 
        \xrightarrow[\text{Rækkeoperation}]{\text{\small \(\mbf{r_1} + \mbf{r_2} \to \mbf{r_1}\)}}
        \tikzmarknode{ar1}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]} \\
        &\hspace{4cm}\tikzmarknode{ar2}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[arrow, postaction={decoration={text along path, text align=center, reverse path, raise=-12pt, text={|\color{blue}|Skalering af pivotelement}}, decorate}] (ar1.east) to[out=-40, in=10] (ar2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Note: When pasting this code into a new document, you'll be faced with the exact same errors as I showed you so you can further inspect them there if you want. Just remember to delete the part of postaction, compile without it and then recompile again with it and it'll work.
Is there any permanent fix to this problem? Does anyone know why this only happens to me when I use decorations.text and tikzmark together and not when separate?

It's not a bug, it's a series of unfortunate ... features.
TL;DR On first compilation, you are trying to work with a trivial non-trivial path. What you are trying to do fails dismally on such a path, causing the document compilation to abort. Removing the problematic code means that the first compilation completes, after which the path is no longer trivial and can compile. There are various solutions, one of which is to use the min distance key on the to path which will ensure that even on first compilation then the path is not trivial.

This is quite a fascinating edge case. To understand it, you need to know a bit about how TikZ remembers coordinates.  For this case, the tikzmark library can be viewed as just an interface to this facility (it is capable of much more than this, but for this situation that's all that's important).
Suppose you have a tikzpicture with a node you want to use later in a different tikzpicture:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (A) at (1,2) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}

When TikZ remembers the position of A then it actually remembers two pieces of information: the coordinates of A internal to the tikzpicture, and the location of the origin of that tikzpicture on the page. The first of these is known as soon as A has been processed, and so is available straightaway within the document. The second of these can only be known once TikZ has constructed the page and so can only be known after the page is done, which makes it hard to use the information to draw anything else on the page! To get round this, TikZ writes that information to the aux file to make it available on the next run.
Now, when you refer to a node in another tikzpicture:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (0,0) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

then TikZ does several things. It calculates the position of A by doing the following: it knows the position of A relative to A's origin, then it computes the relative positions of the origins of the two pictures, and uses that to adjust the position of A to the current picture's origin.
This can only be correct after at least one run, since it requires TikZ to know the origins of both pictures. Prior to that information being available, TikZ still knows A's position relative to its origin, so it just uses that relative to the current origin as a "best guess".
So on the first run, your coordinates (ar1.east) and (ar2.east) are calculated as being their relative positions to their respective origins, but then taken as being relative to the origin of the new tikzpicture.
And here's where one of the series of unfortunate features occurs. Your matrices are exactly the same size, so the positions of (ar1.east) and (ar2.east) relative to their own origins are exactly the same (my compiler measures them as being (65.15819pt,3.0pt)).
So until the information is recorded in the aux file, the path you are working with is:
\draw[...] (65.15819pt,3.0pt) to[out=-40,in=10] (65.15819pt,3.0pt);

Now, in the absence of further information, the to path places its control points in the direction given by out and in at a distance proportional to the distance between the start and end.  Your bezier curve becomes:
--- current soft path ---
\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {65.15819pt}{3.0pt}
\pgfsyssoftpath@curvetosupportatoken {65.15819pt}{3.0pt}
\pgfsyssoftpath@curvetosupportbtoken {65.15819pt}{3.0pt}
\pgfsyssoftpath@curvetotoken {65.15819pt}{3.0pt}

Incidentally, my spath3 library is quite useful here in seeing what the underlying path actually is.  The above was produced by adding the key spath/show current path (and loading the tikzlibrary spath3).
This is what I'm calling a trivial non-trivial path.  It is non-trivial in the sense that it has a non-trivial component (a curve).  However, that is in itself trivial because it doesn't do anything.
Now we need to consider what you are asking of this trivial path.  You are asking to decorate it, with quite a complicated decoration.  That decoration isn't designed for trivial paths, and it doesn't have a failsafe to detect such paths.  So it gets to a point where it has to divide by the distance between points on the curve, and ... it fails.
On my system, the decoration causes sufficient failures that the compilation itself fails.  This means that the aux file never gets updated, and so the next run behaves just like the first and creates the trivial path that causes the problem.
Commenting out the decoration allows TeX to process the picture without so many errors and so it writes to the aux file, whereupon the path will be sufficiently big to no longer cause problems.
Incidentally, it is not just the decoration that complains about the trivial path.  The bendings library also causes complaints - since adding a non-trivial arrow to a trivial path is problematic - but the bendings library doesn't cause so many errors, and TeX is happy to allow compilation to continue.
There are two possible solutions:

Prevent the creation of an empty path in the first place.
Adding the key min distance=5mm does this as it forces the control points to be at least 5mm from the starting and ending points of the curve.  When the curve is properly rendered, this minimum is easily exceeded so it doesn't change the definition of the final curve.  But on first run, when the path would otherwise be trivial, it adds a little bit of size to it.
Another way is to avoid having the nodes be exactly the same size, so that their positions relative to their origins is no longer the same.  I notice that you have an \hspace{4cm} before the second matrix, if you put that inside the \tikzmarknode then it changes the size without changing the final location of the point you are actually interested in.

Prevent the decoration (and arrow) of a trivial path.
I suppose there could be some way of detecting a trivial path deep in the decoration code, but without that then a judicious \iftikzmark (as mentioned by Sam Carter) can protect the decoration.  Actually, we use the key if picture id which is a key version of \iftikzmark.  Wrapping this around the problematic arrow and decorate keys means that they don't get called until the necessary information has been stored in the aux file.


Here's some code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/718082/86}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  tikzmark,
  arrows.meta,
  spath3, % <-- used for a bit of diagnostics
  bending,
  positioning,
  decorations.text
}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style={
    -{Stealth[
        blue,
        length=3mm
      ]
    },
    line width=0.5mm,
    red
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Reduceret rækkeechelonform} \\
        &\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right] 
        \xrightarrow[\text{Rækkeoperation}]{\text{\small \(\mbf{r_1} + \mbf{r_2} \to \mbf{r_1}\)}}
        \tikzmarknode{ar1}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]} \\
        &\hspace{4cm}\tikzmarknode{ar2}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[
  if picture id={ar1}{arrow}{}, % <-- only add the arrow once the tikzmark is defined
  postaction={
    decoration={
      text along path,
      text align=center,
      reverse path,
      raise=-12pt,
      text={|\color{blue}|Skalering af pivotelement}
    },
    if picture id={ar1}{decorate}{}, % <-- only decorate the path once the tikzmark is defined
  },
  spath/show current path % <-- this writes the path to the terminal
] (ar1.east) to[
  out=-40,
  in=10,
  min distance=5mm, % <-- prevents creation of a trivial path
] (ar2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Veeeery profound answer - Thank you very much for taking the necessary time and really breaking down the problem so even someone like me can grasp what's going on! I see that you included both of your suggested possible solutions in the coding example, but you don't need to use both together, right? But if you do use both together, would that "reinforce" the code further? Because the picture id controls when the other elements are added to the line meanwhile min distance prevents the creation of a trivial place in the first place. Thus, a fusion of these would be "stronger"?

You can avoid the problem by using \iftikzmark{⟨name⟩}{⟨true code⟩}{⟨false code⟩} to check if the coordinate is already available and only draw your arrow if true. This avoids running in the division-by-zero error on the first compilation.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows.meta, bending, positioning, decorations.text}
\tikzset{arrow/.style={-{Stealth[blue, length=3mm]}, line width=0.5mm, red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &\hspace{3cm}\textbf{Reduceret rækkeechelonform} \\
        &\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right] 
        \xrightarrow[\text{Rækkeoperation}]{\text{\small \(\mbf{r_1} + \mbf{r_2} \to \mbf{r_1}\)}}
        \tikzmarknode{ar1}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]} \\
        &\hspace{4cm}\tikzmarknode{ar2}{\left[\begin{array}{rrr|rrr}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & -1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -2\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
        \end{array}\right]}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\iftikzmark{ar1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[arrow, postaction={decoration={text along path, text align=center, reverse path, raise=-12pt, text={|\color{blue}|Skalering af pivotelement}}, decorate}] (ar1.east) to[out=-40, in=10] (ar2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}}{}

\end{document}



Ooooh, does that mean that the issue arises due to the fact that decorations.text can't detect whether or not I've actually used the node which I marked in the other environment from tikzpicture? And also, I see you only used \iftikzmark on the marked node to the first coordinate. Does that mean that you don't have to identify the node which the line is being drawn to?

@Atex The remember picture option and, by extend, tikzmarks work because they write the coordinates to an auxiliary file during the first run and then read them from there on the next run. During the first run, the real coordinates aren't yet available. Normally some default value do a good job to avoid compilation errors, but they will be the same for both coordinates, which makes it difficult to calculate the distance etc. That's what I think causes the divided by zero problem in your code.

Based on my understanding of your response, you essentially suspect that the fault lies with tikzmark not being properly optimized to cooperate with decorations.text, right? Because I've used tikzmark with no compilation issues with other libraries before. Take a look at the code from this question of mine a few days ago, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/717887/how-to-make-text-appear-in-front-of-fill-when-using-tikzmarknode
This compiles completely fine and uses other libraries. Also, do you happen to know where to contact tikz developers? I believe

this is an issue which should be reported to the developers themselves so that they can fix the root cause of the problem internally

This is not a fault, this is how remember picture works. It needs two compilations.

But it should be able to compile twice without an issue, right? That's where the problem arises when using decorations.text. It doesn't compile without issues. Hence why I think it's a fault which must be fixed, right?
